# Tortoise error while trying to see diff

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

While trying to view changes that I made to a file I get the following error:

[image]

I installed the latest TortoiseSVN 1.7.11, Build 23600 - 64 Bit , 2012/12/12 19:08:52

Restarted my computer. Ran ["Clean up"](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html) on the folder in which this file is located. Still getting this error.

**UPDATE:** Opened tmp file in Notepad++. There are NULL characters added to the bottom of the file.  I was able to fix the problem by removing these characters.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how the NUL characters got in the file(in main file not tmp). Removed NUL characters, checked it in. Then made a change to a file and did a diff and diff works.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you saved the file as Unicode rather than ASCII (which is what the last line of the error is suggesting you check). So there's nothing wrong with your computer or your environment to be "cleaned". Check the file encoding and change it to ASCII if it turns out to be Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, all of the files including the one that is having problems have UTF-8 encoding. I updated my questions with some more details on the problem.